# Горизонтальное меню с прокруткой

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Нужно реализовать горизонтальную прокрутку для мобильных устройств, как у гугла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С применением скриптов, если необходимо.

Примерный код:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300);

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    background: #CFD8DC;
}
.container {
    width: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: calc(50vh - 240px) 0 0 calc(50% - 160px);
    background: #1565C0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    height: 480px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
header, nav {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

header {
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font: 24px/40px 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

nav ul {
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a {
    font: 18px/30px 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #aae;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
 <header>
  <h1>Site Title</h1>
 </header>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: видимо вам копать в сторону "Перетаскивание jQuery Mobile"

Answer (score 1):

Добавил `.scroller` в `html`:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Site Title</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
    <div class="scroller">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

И добавил в `css` чуток:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav .scroller {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}
nav ul {
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

У nav `.scroller` высота с запасом на всякий случай чтобы не отображалась полоса прокрутки.

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/175k4yyx/